# Automate screenshots for Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, screenshot

I have an app to publish on Google Play Store. The app comes with a lot of different languages and I need to provide screenshots for every single one of them.
It's time consuming so I'm looking for a solution to automate the process.
I found this [one (Screengrab)](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/screengrab#readme%20). The problem is, you need to install a separated component and it's only available for Lunix platform when I'm currently running Windows.

Do you know any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools at the market that can help you with the creation of all required localized screenshots in different resolutions.

##### TOOLS

Here is a tool where you can export different resolutions and localizations with very less effort.

- [Launchmatic](https://www.launchmatic.app/)

Furthermore you can find an overview of different tools that can help you with an easy screenshot creation.

[image: ScreenshotToolsOverview]

- [Screenshot Tools Overview](https://www.iwantanelephant.com/blog/2020/05/25/create-app-screenshots-for-the-app-store-and-the-play-store/)

##### Uploading process

As an addition, however you create your screenshots, uploading more than 1000 screenshots for the playstore/appstore is still very time consuming.

###### Fastlane

You can setup your own pipeline with fastlane to automate the process of uploading screenshots. Disadvantage: You need to setup the environment for fastlane and learn how to use it.

- [FASTLANE](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane)

###### AppStoreManager

Service that provides an "ready-to-use" solution for uploading your screenshots automatically. Just provide a ZIP file with the screenshots in the right format and let the upload handled via the service.

- [App Store Manager](https://appstoremanager.net/)

Comment: In addition, if want to test a snapshot of screenshots: https://github.com/cashapp/paparazzi